# Update Data from Custom Settings on page layout

Tags: customsetting

Could anyone please advise me on following questions:

I would like to search Custom Settings Data Sets in Eclipse. Which metadata components do I need to add? I have added the Custom Object but I could not find the Data sets.

Answer (score 0):

1. Custom setting is available under custom object. Check there again you will surely find it there.
2. You can go to setup> custom setting > Select your custom setting > manage records and update the records there.

Comment: Hi Tushar, I can see it in Custom Object. What I can't see is 'records' under Manage. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @user47137 with custom setting records doesn't move. You need custom metadata for that. You need to manually create record for it.